# CKAN and NGINX conf for running CKAN under URL /path/

Tags: nginx, url, ckan

I have been setting up CKAN 2.9 in a local Debian Buster VM, by following the [instructions on how to install from source](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html) and [deployment](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/installing/deployment.html).

I got CKAN to run, using NGINX, UWSGI and Supervisor, however, I got on to trouble, when I try to change the URL path where CKAN is running.

See CKAN runs fine in http://192.168.60.11/ but I **want it to run in http://192.168.60.11/ckan**

In order to do so I change the in ckan.ini `ckan.site_url to` ckan.site_url = [http://192.168.60.11/ckan`](http://192.168.60.11/ckan%60)

And the NGINX default site conf to:

```
    location /ckan/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_cache_valid 30m;
        proxy_cache_key $host$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;
        # In emergency comment out line to force caching
        # proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    }
```

Reload nginx.service and restarted supervisior.service

http://192.168.60.11/ckan/ brings me to CKNA landing page, but non of the CSS/JS/Images are loaded. In the browser I loading errors such as: `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://192.168.60.11/webassets/vendor/d8ae4bed_jquery.js”.`

And if I click in the link to datasets I am directed to http://192.168.60.11/dataset/, and not http://192.168.60.11/ckan/dataset/

And in  /etc/ckan/default/uwsgi.ERR:
`2020-08-30 19:19:41,554 INFO  [ckan.config.middleware.flask_app]  / render time 0.114 seconds [pid: 7699|app: 0|req: 53/53] 127.0.0.1 () {42 vars in 767 bytes} [Sun Aug 30 19:19:41 2020] GET / => generated 13765 bytes in 122 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 3 headers in 106 bytes (1 switches on core 0)`

So it seems that CKAN is missing some configuration parameter to make it aware of the URL path. Any ideas how? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# ckan.ini
ckan.site_url = "http://public.domain" # no path suffix here
ckan.root_path = "/prefix"
```

```
# nginx config
location /prefix/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; # no path suffix here
}
```

Answer was in [CKAN documentation](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-root-path)

And nginx location just has to change from `/` to `/custom/path`